# How to pronounce лёгкий

Tags: произношение

I understand that every language has tricky words, meaning, words that do not follow the normal sounds or conventions of most words or letters. However, I do want to ensure I am being taught this word correctly so that I can practice learning it correctly.

The word: `лёгкий`

The course I'm taking pronounces it to where it almost sounds like: `loo-skee` or `luiskee`

What is correct? Or is this correct?

Comment: I don't think that this word is tricky. Voiced consonants are often read as voiceless in a non-stressed syllable. The exact rules may be tricky though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics) http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Звонкие_согласные

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transcription is [l'oxk'ij'], where x is for fricative guttural sound and apostrophee is for palatalisation of the previous consonant. [o] is under stress. Palatalisation of x is facultative. [j] is quite frequently omitted, as in all the forms with [ij] at the end, but it is not the most correct way of pronunciation.
The word is tricky, because it has *[γk']->[xk'] where *[gk']-> *[kk']-> [k'] is expected. It is a trace of the ancient state of the language where г was pronounced as fricative sound, [γ]. "->" is for "became".
Dissimilation could also happen - plosive-plosive became fricative-plosive for distinction.

Comment: -1. Еру [j] is never omitted in Russian speech. At least not more frequently than any other consonant at the end of a word.

Comment: There is nothing correct in omitting of the [j'], but there are sounds that are phonetically likelier to be omitted than others, and [j'] is an obvious and well-known example - as well as [w] for languages that have it.

Answer (score 4):

Quite often you can find answer to such questions [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).
So, the phonetic transcription is [ˈlʲɵxʲ.kʲɪj] which roughly can be transmitted as
liokhkiy ("kh" like Scotsmen spell "ch" in Loch Ness).

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used Forvo? It's a site where you can listen to native speakers pronouncing various words in their languages. Here's лёгкий:

http://forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/
http://forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/

By the way, I feel your pain. As a learner of Russian I, too, have mispronounced this word a few times myself! Specifically, I pronounced г as /g/ instead of /x/.

Answer (score 0):

In Moscow version of Russian it is pronounced close to lioghky. Soft L. Then "'о" which together will produce sound like l'o. Close to sound depicted by ё letter. GH is actually somewhere between G and H. Closer to just H. In some cases you will just hear air exit like in "kh" sound.

Comment: close to sound depicted by letter ё? Лёгкий IS with letter ё. It is just frequent deёfication of texts that may make one think it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The Russian phonetical transcription of this word is

[л'охк'ий'] where the apostrophe denotes the softness.

It is read totally following the rules of reading.

You can listen to the correct pronunciation [here](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/en-ru/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).