# Pronunciation of "лёгкий" and "легкий"

Tags: произношение, правописание, буква-ё

I read in [Pushkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pushkin)'s *[Дружба](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/about-pushkins-%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0-how-to-read-it)* the word **"легкий"**, an adjective meaning "slight". There's even [an interesting thread](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4103/how-to-pronounce-%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1) on Russian S.E. about the modern pronouciation of the word.

I noticed two ways to write it : either **легкий** (as Puskin did) either **лёгкий** as [modern dictionaries do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Hence my questions :

(1) which phonological/orthographic shift explains both spellings ? I can't see anything helpfull in [the Wikipedia article dedicated to the reforms of Russian orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_Russian_orthography).

(2) how was the word was pronounced at Pushkin's times ?

Comment: It's a common issue omitting "umlaut" over "Ё" letter. Although this is thought to be an error yet everyone does this ten times a day. No spelling is shifted.

Comment: @user4419802 This is not an error. In many dictionaries words that differ only in "ё/е" are listed as if there is [no difference in them](http://www.wikiznanie.ru/ru-wz/index.php/%D0%81_(%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)): "Слова на букву ё сортируются так же, как если бы они были на букву е, но при этом если слова различаются только на е — ё, то слово на ё ставится после. Такой порядок принят в подавляющем большинстве печатных словарей и энциклопедий." Also there is no need to disambiguate two words (небо/нёбо) as only word лёгкий exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Letter ё is optional, it is usually replaced by е. We have a number of questions about this letter on this site, for example: [Using written е instead of ë](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/6770/551),
[Is 'ё' a distinct letter, or is it just 'е' with a diaeresis?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1465/551),  [What are all the times where "е" changes to "ё"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/4304/551). In short, letter ё is always used only in dictionaries, text for beginners and children, uncommon foreign words (like geographical names) and in cases when difference between word with ё and е is not obvious from the context (like небо (sky) and нёбо (roof of mouth)).

For modern reader it is definitely лёгкий. As for Pushkin times - I'm not sure what was the pronunciation at those times. Usually you notice the difference when two words stand at the end of the verse and should be rhymed (like Ольга/фольга pair which currently have different stresses, but at the beginning of the XX century both words had a stress on a first syllable).

But even when two words happen at the end of a poem's line, it is hard to tell should those words be pronounced with ё or with е. A [long article about letter ё](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/) has the following example (by academic Vinogradov) of Pushkin's Poltava:

> Тесним мы шведов рать за ратью;
> Темнеет слава их **знамен**,
> И бога брани благодатью
> Наш каждый шаг **запечатлен**?

According to Vinogradov here both words are likely using "е" (знам**е**н/запечатл**е**н), but we cannot tell for sure.

Another example where there is е and not ё is verses from Krylov's fable "Лебедь, Щука и Рак" (example from [Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%81#.D0.98.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2_XVII.E2.80.94XIX_.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B2)):

> Когда в товарищах согласья нет —
> На лад их дело не пойдет

Here, in Krylov's times пойдет was pronounced as е as can be seen from the rhymed нет/пойдет. Interestingly, in modern textbook for pupils пойдет in this verse is written using ё: пойд**ё**т.

---

Looks like it was pronounced as л**е**гкий in Pushkin times. According to [Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%81#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.8F) the letter **ё**'s was printed for a first time in 1795. Before that time a number of letter combinations served to resemble this sound (о, ьо, їô, ió, ио). However Google Books has a book printed in 1792, which is entitled ["Новый **легкий** и самый безопасый способ лѣчения чесотки"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Xa9iAAAAcAAJ). If it has to be pronounced as ё there should be one of this combinations used: о, ьо, їô, ió, ио. Since it is not so, it has to be read as "е".

Comment: Thank you very much : the links you give are very usefull.

Comment: On the last paragraph: no, orthography with e was enforced by some people when the reading has long been ['о]. There's a guy (forgot the name) who even explicitly writes in XVIII century: "We do say in casual speech: Пьотр, Иван, идите сюда, but we should write Петр".

Comment: Or, the poets could make use of archaic pronunciation for the sake of rhyme.